# UnicodeEncodeError in python3 program

Tags: python, unicode

the program is suppose to write all files on the hard drive to a file. when i run it in idle it runs until it hits a specific file and then gives me an error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2122' in position 143: character maps to < undefined >

```
#! python3

import os

nfile=open('c:\\users\\computer 6\\desktop\\HardDrive.txt','w')

for folder,subfolder,files in os.walk('c:\\'):
 if len(files) != 0:
  for i in range(len(files)):
   nfile.write(os.path.join(folder,files[i])+'\n')
 else:
  continue

nfile.close()

print('Log complete.')
```

i'm guessing this is because the file contains a Spanish letter?

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Answer (score 1):

Specify an encoding that supports all Unicode characters.  `open` defaults to `locale.getpreferredencoding()`.  `\u2122` is a trademark symbol and is not supported by your default encoding:

```
#! python3
import os

with open('c:\\users\\computer 6\\desktop\\HardDrive.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as nfile:
    for folder,subfolders,files in os.walk('c:\\'):
        for file in files:
            nfile.write(os.path.join(folder,file) + '\n')

print('Log complete.')
```

Answer (score -2):

> EDIT: I see I've missed some points in the question and this answer
>   isn't right indeed. So please forget the following (I don't delete it
>   only in a  "historical" purpose).

You're most probably right. Had the same problem with french characters, solved this way:

```
    for f in next(os.walk(full_path))[2]:
        ##
        #   @todo The following line is a hack to avoid encoding errors,
        #         it would be better to find a way to avoid doing this
        #         encoding/decoding on each file.

        f = f.encode('utf-8', 'replace').decode()

        file_name, extension = os.path.splitext(f)

        etc.
```

Comment: This discards data, when all you need to do is specify an encoding for `open` to use when writing the data. The file system is already being read correctly (Windows NT and higher encode file names in UTF-16 only, so Python has no trouble reading the names, only writing them out when the file wasn't opened with an appropriate encoding, e.g. UTF-8 or UTF-16). Also, what the heck is `natural_sort`?

Comment: ` f = f.encode('utf-8', 'replace').decode()` doesn't do anything.  UTF-8 supports all of Unicode, so nothing to replace, and `.decode()` defaults to `utf8` on Python 3 and reverses the previous `.encode()`.

Comment: Well, almost nothing...Unicode surrogates in the range U+D800 - U+DFFF will get replaced, but they shouldn't occur in Python 3 Unicode strings.

Comment: I used this when I had wrongly encoded characters in file names and it solved the problem, so it really does something. It may lead to lose some information indeed, but there was no other way to read the file names. Now, maybe it's too destructive for this case indeed. Sorry about this `natural_sort`, this has nothing to do with my answer, I remove it.

Comment: @zezollo: It's not possible to have wrongly encoded characters on a Windows native file system. They're native Unicode, encoded as UTF-16...

Comment: @ShadowRanger the files I had to deal with may came from anywhere. But I see I've missed parts of the question and understand why my answer doesn't match the question.